# Calculate The Reward Per Hash

Tags: mining, mining-pools

can we calculate the reward per hash ? like [coin-hive.com](http://coin-hive.com)

coin hive formula :

```
(<solved_hashes>/<global_difficulty>) * <block_reward> * 0.7
```

ex : difficulty of 74.244G / average block reward of 5.57 XMR

```
(<solved_hashes>/74244290023) * 5.57 XMR * 0.7 = 0.000053 XMR per 1M hashes
```

Does it work for other pools ? (to calculate total earnings from total hash?)

Comment: nop, i need to calculate total earnings per total hash

Comment: Retracted flag as you state it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: aren't hashes of a different difficulty?

Comment: yes i need figure out how and why coin-hive calculate total earnings from total hash with that formula
(<solved_hashes>/<global_difficulty>) * <block_reward> * 0.7

Comment: @arefemami probably because they have a set difficulty